# Retrieving data to an array returns empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, react-hooks

I created a simple application using Node, React and Mongo. When I try to retrieve the data from Mongo, the array to which I'm trying to populate the data returns an empty array.

Adding Data works fine.

My code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

const ListQualityGD = () => {
    const [qgd_list, setQgd_list] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/qualities');
                setQgd_list(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(qgd_list); // Log qgd_list to check the data received
    }, [qgd_list]);

    const delQualityGD = async (id) => {
        try {
            await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/qualities/${id}`);
            setQgd_list(qgd_list.filter((qualities) => qualities._id !== id));
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error deleting ', error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>List</h2>
            <ul>
                {qgd_list.map(qualities => (
                    <li key={qualities._id}>
                        {qualities.Ref_Id} -{qualities.Tech} - {qualities.Project} - {qualities.Project_Clip} - {qualities.Upload_Date} - {qualities.Return_Date} - {qualities.AIP} - {qualities.QC} - {qualities.Remark} - {qualities.Return_Type} - {qualities.QA_Remarks} - {qualities.Mistake_Label_In_PT} - {qualities.Local_Jira} - {qualities.Local_Jira_Date_Raised} - {qualities.Me_Jira} - {qualities.Me_Jira_Date_Raised} - {qualities.Final_Answer_Date} - {qualities.Compliance_Approval} - {qualities.Applicable_Month} - {qualities.Applicable_Year} - {qualities.User}
                        View | <button onClick={() => delQualityGD(qualities._id)}>Delete</button> | Edit
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ListQualityGD;
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Have you tried console logging your results? Have you tried to debug the application?

Comment: Yes. I tried. It returns an empty array.

Comment: `fetchData()` is asynchronous, but you're not awaiting it. So you're trying to use the result before it has been filled in.